# Loop to create dummy variable R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to generate dummy variables (must be 1/0) using a loop based on the most frequent response of a variable. After lots of googling, I haven't managed to come up with a solution. I have extracted the most frequent responses (strings, say the top 5 are "A","B",...,"E") using

`top5<-names(head(sort(table(data$var1), decreasing = TRUE),5)`

I would like the loop to check if another variable ("var2") equals A, if so set =1, OW =0, then give a summary using aggregate(). In Stata, I can refer to the looped variable i using `i' but not in R...  The code that does not work is:

```
for(i in top5) {
   data$i.dummy <- ifelse(data$var2=="i",1,0)
   aggregate(data$i.dummy~data$age+data$year,data,mean)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you have quotes around the `i`?  you're comparing `var2` to the character `"i"` rather than the variable `i`... also, faster than `ifelse` would be `as.integer(data$var2==i)`.

Comment: is the below what you were looking for? If not please add some detail about what you were hoping to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want one column per item in your top 5 then I would use `sapply` along the elements in `top5`. No need for `ifelse` because `==` compares and gives `TRUE` or 1 if the comparison is TRUE and 0 otherwise

Here we cbind a matrix of 5 columns, one each for each element of `top5` containing 1 if the row in `data$var2` equals the respective element of 'top5':

```
data <- cbind( data , sapply( top5 , function(x) as.integer( data$var2 == x ) ) )
```

If you want one column for matches of any of `top5` it's even easier:

```
data$dummies <- as.integer( data$var2 %in% top5 )
```

The `as.integer()` in both cases is used to turn `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `1` and `0` respectively.

A cut down example to illustrate how it works:

```
set.seed(123)
top2 <- c("A","B")
data <- data.frame( var2 = sample(LETTERS[1:4],6,repl=TRUE) )

#  Make dummy variables, one column for each element in topX vector
data <- cbind( data , sapply( top2 , function(x) as.integer( data$var2 == x ) ) )
data
#  var2 A B
#1    B 0 1
#2    D 0 0
#3    B 0 1
#4    D 0 0
#5    D 0 0
#6    A 1 0

#  Make single column for all elements in topX vector
data$ANY <- as.integer( data$var2 %in% top2 )
data
#  var2 ANY A B
#1    B   1 0 1
#2    D   0 0 0
#3    B   1 0 1
#4    D   0 0 0
#5    D   0 0 0
#6    A   1 1 0
```

Answer (score 5):

See `fortune(312)`, then read the help `?"[["` and possibly the help for `paste0`.

Then possibly consider using other tools like `model.matrix` and `sapply` rather than doing everything yourself using loops.